# How to compile C function at specific address Visual C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, compilation, reverse-engineering

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.
I have a compiled dll which sets some variables and uses some functions at some addresses when loaded like this:

```
#define func_address 0xdeadbeef;
typedef int func(int a, int b);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved ) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        func* f = (func*)func_address;
        int c = f(3, 1);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I need to compile PE where specific function would compile at specific address so that when dll module loaded it would have done its job:

```
int func(int a, int b) {       /* <= Compile this at address 0xdeadbeef */
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    //somestuff
    return 0;
}
```

The most promising I could find was that construction, but seems this only for keil arm compiler http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ARMCC/armcc_chr1359124981140.htm:

```
int func(int a, int b) __attribute__((at(0xdeadbeef)));
```

So the question is how can I archive function compilation at specific address inside PE?

Comment: `0xdeadbeef` is an **odd** value so it is not the "aligned" address expected for a function.

Comment: Sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What's the ultimate goal of this exercise? What do you believe you need all this for?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the dll has a function that xors passed buffer of passed length with some unknown key which is well-packed and cant be read with debugger then it calls known offset function which I want to replace and dump that key.

Comment: Can't you run the original EXE under debugger, and put a breakpoint at that address? Or patch the DLL and have the function call some other address?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that dll is protected and using anti-debugging techniques, and does not run without highest privileges. Whenever I attach debugger or set breakpoint the program crashes. I want to create a fake pe that would load the module which would hook desired functions at known addresses which would dump xored 0x0 buffer to file what leads me to obtain that key.

Comment: Well, I don't know of a way to trick VC++ into placing a function at a particular address. You might perhaps be able to allocate memory at that address with `VirtualAlloc`, and populate it with machine code at runtime.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik dll targets function located in the beginning of the file like 0x00401000, i can't alloc memory there because a new compiled program uses this space.

Comment: Maybe you could use [`/BASE` linker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/base-base-address) to move the executable down.

Comment: Would just knowing the address be of help?  If so, MAYBE you could place the function immediately after a static array of length LEN.  Then, perhaps the function will reside in memory adjacent to the array -- at offset array + LEN (or near it).  I know, it's a stupid idea, sorry... but in some applications/OSs...